# Finding count and data in single mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have two tables. Cities, Localities.

```
Cities:  
    id | name  
Localities:  
    id | city_id | name
```

Can I make a single query to get the localities list of the cities(only 10 rows per city), also the count of the localities in that city?

I know I can do that in 2 different queries.

Please suggest if it can be done using Django querysets.

Models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)    

class Locality(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,related_name='LocalityCity')
```

Comment: What is your result supposed to look like? One row per locality showing the count in a column? One row per locality plus one row showing the count? One row per city showing the localities and the count?

Comment: 10 rows of localities per city with actual count of that city. Eg. `city1,locality1,13`, `city1,locality2,13`,`city1,locality3,13`...so on till `city1,locality10,13`, and then `city2,locality14,8` till `city2,locality15,8` and so on for all cities.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
( select c.id as city_id, count(l.id) as "localities count per city"
  from cities as c
  inner join localities as l on l.city_id = c.id ) as localities_count_per_city
inner join
( select c.id as city_id, c.name, l.name
  from cities as c
  inner join localities as l on l.city_id = c.id
  limit 10) as localities_per_city ) as localities_per_city
on localities_count_per_city.city_id = localities_per_city.city_id
```

this should join the respective localities per city count with every locality by city row.

Answer (score 0):

You should have mentioned the models instead of SQL table schemas. Here is how you can query them:

```
cities = City.objects.annotate(num_cities=Count("locality"))
for city in cities:
    print(city.locality_set, city_num_cities)
```

Comment: I thought it is quite predictable with SQL schema. BTW, How are you getting the locality set?

Comment: Reverse relationships are created by Django, by default https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make a single query to get the localities list of the
>   cities(only 10 rows per city), also the count of the localities in
>   that city?

Assuming your models are:

```
class Locality(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)    

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    locality = models.ManyToMany(Locality)
```

You can get your result like this:

```
all_cities = City.object.all()
for city in all_cities:
   print('City: {} Total Localities: {}'.format(city.name, city.locality_set.count()))
   for loc in city.locality_set.all():
       print('\t{}'.format(loc.name))
```

In the above snippet, there are *two* queries being executed - but django querysets are cached, so you can rest assured the correct query is being executed each time.

If you want to get it done at once, then you need to use aggregates:

```
from django.db.models import Count

all_cities = City.objects.all().annotate(localities=Count('locality'))
for city in all_cities:
   print('City: {} Total Localities: {}'.format(city, city.localities))
```

Comment: Can you please correct your answer based on the models I mentioned?

Comment: Try and see if you can do it for yourself, and if you run into a problem; then ask.